# WSO2 3.2.0 - Publish an API - ERROR - APIGatewayManager Error

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have a docker environment running openldap, mysql, wso2is and wso2am. I'm trying to publish an API using API Manager Publisher and I'm facing the following error:

docker log:

```
[2021-03-18 21:40:32,764]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@wso2.com@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2021-03-18 21:40:32,764+0000]
[2021-03-18 21:40:32,899] ERROR - APIGatewayManager Error occurred when publish to gateway Production and Sandbox
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while Deploying API 
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIGatewayAdminClient.deployAPI_aroundBody14(APIGatewayAdminClient.java:215) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl_6.7.206.jar:?]
```

Caused by:

```
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while obtaining API information from gateway. null
at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
```

More info:

```
[2021-03-18 21:40:33,178]  INFO - DataBridge user admin@wso2.com connected
[2021-03-18 21:40:33,187] ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://172.29.0.5:9712.
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://172.29.0.5:9712.

[2021-03-18 21:40:33,234]  INFO - CarbonAuthenticationUtil 'admin@wso2.com@carbon.super [-1234]' logged in at [2021-03-18 21:40:33,233+0000]
[2021-03-18 21:40:33,264] ERROR - APIGatewayManager Error occurred when check api is published on gatewayProduction and Sandbox
```

**Where is defined port 9712 for ssl?** Because I don't have this port available on docker: 
wso2am:3.2.0-alpine              "/home/wso2carbon/wa…"   7 days ago          Up 12 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:8243->8243/tcp, 5672/tcp, 9099/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8280->8280/tcp, 9443/tcp, 9611/tcp, 9711/tcp, 9763/tcp, 9999/tcp, 11111/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9444->9444/tcp

I'm using WSO2 IS as key manager and the integration is working. Now my problem is only when I try to publish an API.

wso2is:5.10.0-alpine 
wso2am:3.2.0-alpine

PS: I have disabled network from docker-compose to not have host problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Issue 01:**

```
Caused by: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Error while obtaining API information from gateway. null
```

The above error can be seen most probably due to a connection issue between the Publisher and the Gateway server/s.
To resolve this, you may need to validate the Gateway configuration in the Publisher node. To do that, open the `<PUBLISHER_HOME>/repository/conf/deployment.toml` file and
check whether the following configuration is correct.

```
[[apim.gateway.environment]]
service_url = "https://<hostname_of_the_GW>:9443/services/"
```

**Issue 02:**

```
ERROR - DataEndpointConnectionWorker Error while trying to connect to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://172.29.0.5:9712.
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointLoginException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://172.29.0.5:9712.
```

The above error indicates that the 9712 port is not accessible. This 9712 is the default port which is started by BinaryDataReceiver for Binary SSL Transport and it will be used to authenticate data published to the Traffic Manager. Therefore, you need to make this port available.